# SQL - Hosting offsite or importing each time?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, solr, amazon-s3

I have my main web server and I need a seperate workhorse server, I cant get around this unfortunatly. The workhorse server generates a largeish (+100mb) SQL file which I need to import to the web server every day.

The way I see it, I have two options:

**1. Option one -** Allow the web server to connect to postgreSQL on the workhorse server and import the data directly from postgre running on the workhorse server

**2. Option two -** Export the SQL database from the workhorse server and upload it to AmazonS3. Then download the file from S3 on the web server and import it to postgreSQL server running on the web server.

My main concerns is to keep the system as simple, secure and reliable as possible. I want to limit the chances of the database getting corrupted.

Comment: Option three - The application queries the workhorse. No file transfer of any kind.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is that the same as option 1 though?

Comment: No. In instead of querying the server at the localhost the query is done against the remote host. I don't get why this didn't occur to you. Any problem?

Comment: That is that option 1 is. Is still want to know if this actually has advantages

Comment: Why do you use the term import in option number 1? That leads to the understanding that you are moving the 100mb file. Is that what the query returns?

Comment: Can someone put this in an offical answer so I can accept please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the answers I got, it looks like option 1 is the best best. To use the server as an SQL host and query it directly rather than move the SQL file.

Comment: You should atleast +1 any comments that helped you answer this.